# Using Jackson to parse embedded JSON In another JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is there a way to to tell `Jackson` parser to go to another `JSON` within an external `JSON`?

Just to simplify,  I want to do something like this

```
{
    "id" : 100,
    "myObject" : {
        "embeddedKey" : "embeddedValue"
    }
}
```

Comment: "Yo dwag i heard you liked Json so i put Json in your Json", More seriously, what do you want to do ? Converting Objects in a Object into Json ?

Comment: myObject.json contains all the data 
and I want Jackson to spool myObject.json in to the above json string

Comment: where exactly is myObject.json located...?

Comment: both files are in my project . I need to construct json to mock big BO object. this is way I want this behavior.

Comment: if you want the data parsed together, why do you have it in two separate files?

Comment: Because my main object contains a lot of objects and I thought it will be more usable for future development.  If some other developer want to reuse my json insted of copy paste . Think about this like import jason into json

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to tell Jackson deserializer to *navigate* the *links* specified in some attributes, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read embedded object in Jackson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036530/read-embedded-object-in-jackson)