# Jackson @JsonBackreference for embedded or nested classes

Tags: java, hibernate, jackson

I have parent child relationship build this way (came from legacy system)

```
@Entity
@Table
class A implements Serializable {

    ........
    @jsonmanagedreference("test")  
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="PK.id", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,)
    Set<B> b = new HashSet<B>()

    ......
    setters / getters

}



@Embeddable
class PK {

   @jsonbackreference("tets") // can't find it 
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumns
   A a

}

@Entity
@Table
class B implements Serializable {

   @EmbeddedId
   private PK pk;

   setters / getters 

}
```

It works fine with regular operations, the problem is I can not serialize A object because circular reference. 
After I tried to add  **@jsonmanagedreference** to **A.b** and **@jsonbackreference** to **PK.a** it did not work because it could not find JsonBackReference, is there a way to manage parent child relationship during serialization if child in Embedded class or nested?

Comment: you could put `@JsonIgnore ` on `public B getB()`.

Comment: How would it work? it just skip serialization, I need full object restore after deserialization

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution:
[Read embedded object in Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036530/read-embedded-object-in-jackson)

It worked for me, just using @JsonUnwrapped on embedded class reference and mapping the embedded id with: @JsonIdentityInfo

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "yourEmbeddedIdAtribute")
```